# Arrow function not working in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the  following code below which displays records from an array and is working fine. now I want to add ability to search data

and I have added the following script to enable the search

```
filterRecord = record =>
    record.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1 ||
    record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 ||
    record.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1;
```

I have also tried

```
filterRecord = (record) => (record.name.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 || 
                           record.gender.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1);
```

both code give error unexpected token pointing at **equal to** `(=)` at this line  `filterRecord =`

here is the screenshot
[image]

**Here is the full code**

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.filterRecord = this.filterRecord.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" },
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90", gender: "female" },
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87", gender: "female" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34", gender: "male" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34", gender: "male" },
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19", gender: "male" },
        { name: "tom", Age: "89", gender: "female" }
      ],
      value: "",
      searchdata: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
  filterRecord = record =>
    record.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1 ||
    record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 ||
    record.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Search/Filter Records by name, Age and gender</h3>

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by name, Age and gender"
            id="searchdata"
            name="searchdata"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.searchdata}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.filter(this.filterRecord).map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age} - {obj.gender}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need babel to handle class fields. Changing it into a function exp `filterRecord(record) { ... }` will fix it, but its just a workaround

Comment: @kind how do install babel. it is something like npm install babel. Thanks

Comment: Just look for the docs, yeah its a npm library - you need to add it inside your webpack or so

Comment: It's best to use something like [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) in the beginning. It will automatically create your project and install all the dependencies that you'll need to create a react application. You won't have to worry about Babbel, manually restarting your project etc. The `npm start` script will do everything for you.

Comment: Thanks alot. the error is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well.

I think you didn't install babel and es6/es2015.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.filterRecord = this.filterRecord.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      rec: [
        { name: "Tony", Age: "18", gender: "male" },
        { name: "John", Age: "21", gender: "female" },
        { name: "Luke", Age: "78", gender: "male" },
        { name: "Mark", Age: "90", gender: "female" },
        { name: "Jame", Age: "87", gender: "female" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34", gender: "male" },
        { name: "Franco", Age: "34", gender: "male" },
        { name: "Biggard", Age: "19", gender: "male" },
        { name: "tom", Age: "89", gender: "female" }
      ],
      value: "",
      searchdata: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
  
  filterRecord = record =>
    (record.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1 ||
    record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 ||
    record.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Search/Filter Records by name, Age and gender</h3>

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by name, Age and gender"
            id="searchdata"
            name="searchdata"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.searchdata}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.filter(this.filterRecord).map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.name} - {obj.Age} - {obj.gender}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be silly here but i think your syntax for arrow function is wrong. You didnt wrap your function body in curly braces.
Try this:

```
filterRecord = (record) => {
   return (record.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) > -1 ||
           record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 ||
           record.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) > -1);
}
```

Hope this helps!!